# Move stock availability location in Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, price

Can someone maybe help me to find a way to get the stock availability directly under the price?

I dont think there is a hook for it.

I have also tried to display stock status in price.php and remove the original. But no success so far:

[image: Single product page]

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `single.php` file in your active child theme (or active theme) in: 
   `woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/single.php`
2. Change the code to:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
   * Simple product add to cart
   *
   * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php.
   *
   * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
   * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
   * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
   * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
   * the readme will list any important changes.
   *
   * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
   * @package WooCommerce/Templates
   * @version 3.4.0
   */

   defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

   global $post;

   $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

   if ( ! $short_description ) {
   return;
   }

   global $product;

   if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
   return;
   }

   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product ); // WPCS: XSS ok.

   if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

   <form class="cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

   <?php
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );

   woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
   'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
   'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
   'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
   ) );

   do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
   ?>
   <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
   <?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
   </form>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
3. Add this code to functions.php:

   ```
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
   ```